# Forbid parent div width dynamic height from expanding to fit child content

Tags: html, css

I have a `container` which fits the whole viewport with `nav`, `main` and `footer` nodes. The `main` node needs to fill all of the available space of the page so its height is dynamic. Inside the `main` node I have a short hierarchy of nodes, where `cats` node may not fit the parent.

```
 <div class="container">
  <nav>
    <input />
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class="scrollable">
       <div class="cats">
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" />
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" />
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" />
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cat">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/280/280" />
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <button>
      Click me!
    </button>
  </footer>
</div>
```

I want to force the `scrollable` node to fill the `main` parent, but when its children overflow, show a vertical scrollbar. By any means I do not want the `main` node to resize to fit children, cause this results in content not fitting the viewport.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.scrollable {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.cats {
  flex: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

This solution works... under Chrome. It does not under Firefox. I get the feeling that this chain of `flex` is not the way to go. I will be thankful for any hits how to make it more universal.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ktguLn73/13/

Funny thing is, when I put `overflow-y: scroll` on the `main` node, it works in both Chrome and Firefox. But this is not the result I prefer.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I remember reading an article with a similar problem where firefox wouldnt scroll with flex oveflow. Check out this page and see if it helps: https://moduscreate.com/blog/how-to-fix-overflow-issues-in-css-flex-layouts/

Comment: That was indeed the case, thanks! `min-height: 0` on the container solved the issue. Would you like to create an answer so I could credit you?

Comment: Will do, I think the community prefer it when a question is marked as solved with an answer rather than having it hidden in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember reading an article with a similar problem where firefox wouldnt scroll with flex oveflow. Check out this page and see if it helps: https://moduscreate.com/blog/how-to-fix-overflow-issues-in-css-flex-layouts/

Read through the article and min-height: 0 on the container solved the issue for the layout in firefox.